# Nginx https certbot return 301 -- replace certbot-generated 'if' statements with best practices

Tags: ssl, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, tls1.2, certbot

I am setting up a nginx web server, and have a question about my server block config. FWIW, it's Ubuntu 16.04, Nginx 1.13.10.

I would like to rewrite Certbot's auto-generated code (which uses IF statements for its redirects), using more efficient syntax, per Nginx [Using If](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#using-if) and [If Is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

**Goal:** to redirect each of the 3 non-`https://@` options into one secure `@`. In other words, `http://www.example.com, http://example.com, https://www.example.com` should ALL redirect to `https://example.com` -- but without the IF's.

I have searched keywords like "nginx certbot return 301 redirect" on S.O. and AskUbuntu, but none seem to address the IF issue. Any suggestions, links, and further reading are welcome.

**Questions:**

1. The server currently redirects `http` to `https`, but does not drop `www`. Is this because only some of the servers are listening on ipv6? If not, suggestions please.
2. Will certbot/letsencrypt punish me if I modify its auto-generated code (i.e. will I lose my secure connection)? Or does it only care about good syntax?

Follow-up (I predict the first two will answer the next, but....)

3. Do my proposed changes (commented in the code) look accurate syntax-wise?
4. Any further suggestions for improvement?

**Code:** simplified for clarity of the topic -- but server does https (with an A+ from [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)), and passes `nginx -t`.

aTdHvAaNnKcSe (THANKS in advance)!

```
##
# 0 - main server https @
##
server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    #
    # insert certbot-generated cert, cert-key, options, and dhparam
    # and all the location-related stuff
    #
    # this is working fine. :)
    # But why ipv6only=on ? Pros/cons?
    #
}

##
# 1 - redirect https www to @
##
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    listen 443 ssl;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
    #
    # insert certbot-generated cert, cert-key, options, and dhparam
    #
    # This appears to be secure, but does not actually redirect www to @
    # Is it because it's only listening on ipv4? 
    # Should I add listen [::]:443 ssl; # also ipv6only=on?
}

##
# 2 - redirect http @ to https @
##
server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name example.com;

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    return 404; # managed by Certbot
    #
    # I want to replace entire IF statement with something like:
    # return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    #
    # ?? The 404 is the ELSE part of the conditional, right? Safe to delete? 
}

##
# 3 - redirect http www to https @
##
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name www.example.com;

    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
    #
    # I'd like to replace with something like:
    # return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    #
    # ?? Should I add listen [::]:80; 
    # 
}
```

Comment: Testing proposed changes, server seems to respond as expected. 

On servers 2&3, I deleted the "if" and "return 404" lines, added `return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;`

Added ipv6 to each of the servers that didn't have it: `listen[::]:443 ssl;` and `listen[::]:80;`, respectively. (No `ipv6only=on`, reasoning that it would be redundant.)

This may be a useful suggestion to the folks at Certbot, as it may be more in line with Nginx best practices (and algorithms in general) than the current implementation. 

Any suggestions for improvement are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a basic setup for an https server, per nginx best practices. This redirects all http traffic to https, and redirects the www subdomain to the domain.

You will of course have to copy your location configs (php, .ht, etc.) into the main block, and your certbot configs into **both** https blocks. If you are setting this up as a new server, certbot *should* generate correctly into the right server{} blocks.

I hope this helps someone.

```
# Basic server config, redirecting all http:// and www to https://@

##
# 0 - main server https @
##
server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    #
    # this is your main config. You don't really need to touch the others
    # because they are simple redirects. 
    #
    # include the certbot-generated cert, cert-key, options, and dhparam
    # include all the location configs 
    # include all the php, wordpress, etc.
    #
}

##
# 1 - redirect https www to @
##
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    server_name www.example.com;

    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
    #
    # include certbot-generated cert, cert-key, options, and dhparam
    #
}

##
# 2 - redirect http @ to https @
##
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

##
# 3 - redirect http www to https @
##
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;

    server_name www.example.com;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```